# syncfusion_flutter_pdf 24.1.41 ( removeAt(0) ) showing null check error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

syncfusion_flutter_pdf 24.1.41 ( removeAt(0) ) showing null check error in flutter
this function has to delete pdf page but its not working
i need to delete pdf pages in flutter its a pdf form and I dont know any other way

```
//Loads an existing PDF document
PdfDocument document =
    PdfDocument(inputBytes: File('input.pdf').readAsBytesSync());
 
//Gets the second page of the document
PdfPage page = document.pages[1];

//Removes the second page from the document
document.pages.remove(page);

//Removes the first page from the document
document.pages.removeAt(0);

//Saves the document
File('output.pdf').writeAsBytes(await document.save());

//Disposes the document
document.dispose();

//Loads an existing PDF document
PdfDocument document =
    PdfDocument(inputBytes: File('input.pdf').readAsBytesSync());
 
//Gets the second page of the document
PdfPage page = document.pages[1];

//Removes the second page from the document
document.pages.remove(page);

//Removes the first page from the document
document.pages.removeAt(0);

//Saves the document
File('output.pdf').writeAsBytes(await document.save());

//Disposes the document
document.dispose();
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.